# What is the fastest way to level up in Dragon Age: Inquisition multiplayer?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I want to level up fast in Dragon Age: Inquisition multiplayer but can't find how to farm xp

Answer (score 2):

Just keep playing. A powerful beginner character for me is the Archer, getting Long Shot upgraded at level 4.

With that skill, everything behind your target gets shot with increasing damage.